# EventHub Register Processor inside Azure WebJob not working

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to take the load off my main server. For that I created a micro service to handle my printing task that was consuming a lot and was trying to integrate both by using Azure Event Hubs. The problem is, I can't seem to get the webjob to work. This is the webjob's code:

```cs
public class Functions
{
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static async Task StartConsumerService()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside StartConsumerService - Before GetEventProcessor");
        var eventProcessor = API.Integrations.Azure.EventHub.Client.GetEventProcessor(Constants.Azure.EventHub.Hubs.Print);
        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside StartConsumerService - Before RegisterEventProcessorAsync");
        await eventProcessor.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<PrintEventProcessor>();
        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside StartConsumerService - After RegisterEventProcessorAsync");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is the `Program.cs`:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside Main");
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }


        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside Main - Before JobHost Initialization");
        var host = new JobHost(config);

        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside Main - Before Async Call");
        host.CallAsync(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("StartConsumerService"));
        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside Main - After Async Call");
        host.RunAndBlock();
        Trace.WriteLine("Print - Inside Main - After Run And Block");
    }
}
```

The WebJob is running and the function has been called. I checked that on Azure Portal:

[image]

This is how I trigger the client from my web app:

```cs
var client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(cs);

await client.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message))));
await client.CloseAsync();
```

Still, it never gets consumed by the event processor running on the webjob. Also, none of my traces show up in the log, either the webjob log from SCM, nor from the application logs from Azure WebApp portal.

Any ideas? It's been over a week now and I can't get this to work...

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty bad experiences in the past of `Console.Readline()` call within a webjob (was a left over from a basic move from regular console with a pump & a webjob)

In theory this `Console.Readline()` isn't necessary for keeping the job up & running thanks to `RunAndBlock()`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not related to my problem. Even if I remove it, it's not called. Just to expand a little bit more on that, that console.readline was only a test after the "regular" way didn't work.